# Html iframe suggestion

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

check out the image I have posted

[image]

As you can see I have used an Iframe.everything works fine,once I click on create pdf,there is a page that gets displayed in the iframe instead of the error.The problem arises the first time when I go to the page,since some values are missing,exceptions are thrown.

I tried adding a condition using php to check if the submit button is pressed,so that once pressed I would like the Iframe to get displayed with the result and not with the error

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  ?>
<iframe name="myframe" id="frame1" src="xm4.jsp" alt="" width="1300" height="1000">
</iframe>
<?php}?>
```

But this did not work.So could anyone provide me with sugestions?

Comment: Your iframe works fine. What your problem is depends on the script in your JSP file.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly isn't working? Is $_POST['submit'] set on your first call, so the iframe gets displayed anyway?

You could check for the actual value of submit (if (@$_POST['submit'] == "Create PDF")).

You have to name your submit:

You could also adapt the xm4.jsp to check the required values and display a nice information rather than the error.

Comment: I like your 2nd suggestion,about putting a message.Was thinking to do loading bar,but how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way around this is to hide the iframe and add a click handler to the 'Create pdf' button to show it when it is clicked.

```
<iframe style="display:none" id="frame1" .... />
```

So if you have jquery, you would do

```
$('create_pdf_id').click(function() {
    $("#frame1").show();
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.I tried it,it worked also,but as soon as i clicked it,the exception got displayed first,and then the page i requested.

Comment: I would like to try adding a progress bar but where should I add it?I cant add it to Iframe or can I?